# Azure Service Fabric tx.CommitAsync after each Enqueue/Dequeue?

Tags: performance, azure, collections, azure-service-fabric

In my SF app there are some ReliableQueries with some continiously data flow. Lets say 50 items per single second are enqueued and dequeued by another SF service. Should I call `tx.CommitAsync` after each enqueue/dequeue or it's OK if I commit after 10 items batch for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Batch will always give you the best performance.

Comment: But in other hand, State is replicated to another instances after commiting. So state changes should not be very huge? I mean is there some optimal batch size?

Comment: That is up to you to decide, of course. I would see if I can get all 50 items batched per second, start from there, if it holds, good, if not, reduce by half, etc until you find the optimal batch size.